# IIS7.5 - Dynamic Compression, Server Downtime?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7.5

Good Day,

I need to install the IIS 7.5 Dynamic Compression module on a production server. Does IIS shutdown during the module installation or does it continue running?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The server does seem to shutdown/hold all requests for a split second during the  configuring IIS stage.